Expressing quartic integral in terms of special functions
I would like to calculate the following integral (presumably I terms of special functions available in typical scientific software packages, like scipy):
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda (x^2-d^2)^2}dx
$$
(This is a rather typical integral in physics, describing a model double-well potential or Landau theory of phase transitions.)
Gradshtein&Ryzhik has formulas for a similar integral (GR 3.323-3 and similar GR 3.469-1):
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\beta^2x^4-2\gamma^2x^2}dx=2^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\gamma}{\beta}
e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}}K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}\right),
|\text{arg}\beta|<\frac{\pi}{4},|\text{arg}\gamma|<\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
The integral differs from the integral of interest by the sign of $\gamma^2$.
What interests me is:

whether there is a known way to express the first integral in terms of "standard" special functions?
how to prove the G&R formula? (I tried expansion in series and various substitutions, but I didn't succeed in reducing it to a know expression for modified Bessel functions.)


Mathematica yields the following result under the assumption that $\lambda,d^2$ are both positive: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda (x^2-d^2)^2}dx=\frac{\pi |d|}{2}e^{-\lambda d^4/2}\left[I_{1/4}\left(\frac{\lambda d^2}{2}\right)+I_{-1/4}\left(\frac{\lambda d^2}{2}\right)\right]$$

@Semiclassical Thanks... I am still interested, how it comes about mathematically (and why GR limits to the case $d^2$<0, if it is that easy - $K$ corresponds to a differennce of the Bessels in your expression.)

It's always hard to judge why G&R makes certain choices. My suspicion would be that one can analytically continue $d$ to deduce the Mathematica result from the G&R result (or vice versa). For instance, it should be the case that $I_{\pm 1/4}(ze^{i\pi})=e^{\pm i\pi/4}I_{\pm 1/4}(z)$. But even if I combine this with the connection formula for $K$ as a difference of $I$'s it's not entirely obvious to me that this suffices.

Your integral is
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda (x^2  - d^2 )^2 } {\rm d}x} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda (t - d^2 )^2 } t^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}t} 
\\ & = {\rm e}^{ - \lambda d^4 } \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \lambda t^2  + 2\lambda d^2 t} t^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}t} 
\\ &  = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \lambda d^4 } }}{{(2\lambda )^{1/4} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{{s^2 }}{2} + \sqrt {2\lambda } d^2 s} s^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}s} 
\\ &  = \sqrt \pi  \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}\lambda d^4 } }}{{(2\lambda )^{1/4} }}U\!\left( {0, - \sqrt {2\lambda } d^2 } \right),
\end{align*}
via $(12.5.1)$, where $U$ is the parabolic cylinder function. Now, by $(12.7.10)$ and $(10.34.2)$,
$$
U(0, - z) = \sqrt {\frac{{z{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} }}{{2\pi }}} K_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i}} } \right) = \sqrt {\frac{z}{{2\pi }}} \left( {K_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right) + \sqrt 2 \pi I_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right)} \right).
$$
Using
$$
K_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right) = \frac{\pi }{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {I_{ - 1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right) - I_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right)} \right),
$$
we also have
$$
U(0, - z) = \frac{{\sqrt {\pi z} }}{2}\left( {I_{ - 1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right) + I_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{4}z^2 } \right)} \right).
$$
This will give you the result presented in the comments.

As a partial answer: the integral from Gradshtein&Ryzhik is evaluated by substitution $x=\sqrt{2}\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\sinh(\frac{t}{4})$:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\beta^2x^4-2\gamma^2x^2}dx
&=
e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\beta^2\left(x^2+\frac{\gamma^2}{\beta^2}\right)^2}dx
\\ & =
\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta}e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}}\int_0^{+\infty}
e^{-\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}\left(2\sinh^2 \frac{t}{4}+1\right)^2}\cosh\frac{t}{4}dt\\ &= 
\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta}e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}}\int_0^{+\infty}
e^{-\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}\cosh^2 \frac{t}{2}}\cosh\frac{t}{4}dt\\ &=
\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta}e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{\beta^2}}\int_0^{+\infty}
e^{-\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}(\cosh t+1)}\cosh\frac{t}{4}dt\\&= 
\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta}e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}} 
K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}\right),
\end{align*}
where the standard expression for the Bessel function is used:
$$
K_\nu(z)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-z\cosh t}\cosh \nu t dt
$$
(See, e.g., G&R 8.432-1.)
Given the relation between the modified Bessel functions
$$
K_\nu(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{I_{-\nu}(z)-I_\nu(z)}{\sin\nu\pi}
$$
this is rather similar to the answer for the first integral in the Q., given by mathematica (provided in the comments by @Semiclassical.) However, it is not still clear to me how to get there.

This is too long for a comment, but should be read in relation to Roger V's answer.
Let $z:=\gamma^4/(2\beta^2)$. Then analytically continuing to $\gamma^2\to e^{i\pi}\gamma^2$ amounts to $z\to e^{i 2\pi} z$. In that case, the appropriate analytic continuation is $I_{\pm 1/4}(e^{i 2\pi}z)=e^{\pm i \pi/2}I_{\pm 1/4}(z)$ (see G&R 8.476.4). But at the same time we have $\gamma\to e^{i\pi/2} \gamma$, so combined with the prefactor we have $$\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta}e^{z} K_{1/4}(z)\to \frac{e^{i\pi/2}\gamma}{2\sqrt{2}\beta} \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-i\pi/2}I_{-1/4}(z)-e^{i\pi/2}I_{1/4}(z)}{\sin(\pi/4)}=\frac{\gamma \pi}{4\beta}[I_{-1/4}(z)+I_{1/4}(z)]$$
This agrees with what Mathematica obtains for the $\beta,\gamma$ integral under the assumption $\gamma^2<0$. (I missed this before because I thought $z\to e^{i \pi }z$ instead of $z\to e^{i 2\pi}z$.) So indeed the integral amounts to analytic-continuation of the result in G&R.

For good measure, I'll sketch a second way to arrive at Mathematica's answer. If we replace $\gamma^2\to -\gamma^2$ in Roger V's integral and substitute $u=\beta x^2$, we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta x^4+2\gamma^2 x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2\beta}\int_0^\infty u^{-1/2}e^{2(\gamma^2/\beta)u}e^{-u^2}\,du$$
Expanding the first exponential in powers of $\gamma^2/\beta$ yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma^2/\beta)^k}{2\beta (k!)}\int_0^{\infty} u^{k-1/2}e^{-u^2}du$$
The coefficients are thus all Gaussian integrals and can be expressed in closed form. From here it remains to compare with the power-series definitions of $I_{\pm 1/4}(z)$ and match term-by-term. (This appears to involve some slightly-tedious casework for even vs odd powers, which I will leave to the interested reader.)
